# Using mean value theorem for several variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I found this excercise for a course of calculus in several variables:

Show that exists a number $\theta$, $0<\theta<1$ such that $\frac{2}{\pi}=\cos{\frac{\theta\pi}{2}}+\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\theta)}$ using mean value theorem.

I don know how to begin. I was thinking about the composition of two functions, for example take $x=\cos x, y=\sin{x}$ and try to define a function $f(x,y)$ (defined over the curve that is a circle) though I think that this doesn't function. So could you give some other idea please?

Comment: It's a continuous function of the single variable $\theta$.  You just need the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=\cos \big( \frac{\pi x}{2} \big) + \sin \big(\frac{\pi}{2}(1-x) \big) - \frac{2}{\pi}.$ We have

$f(0) = \cos(0) + \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) - \frac{2}{\pi} = 1+1 - \frac{2}{\pi} > 0$

$f(1) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) + \sin(0) - \frac{2}{\pi} = -\frac{2}{\pi} < 0$

Since, $f$ is continuous and $f(0)f(1) < 0$, the Intermediate Value Theorem gives that $f$ must have a zero in the open iterval $(0,1)$, i.e. there exists a $\theta$ as desired in the problem.